# jquery error on appending html content to div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code I am having:

```
<div id="removequestions"></div>

var html += '<input type=radio name=questions />';
$.('#removequestions').append(html);
```

The javascript error I am getting on executng the above code is:

```
XML filter is applied to non-XML value (function (a, b) {return new c.fn.init(a, b);})
```

Any idea why this error occurs. I want to add radio button dynamically.

Comment: I am not sure about your error <might be more info needed> but see here: http://jsfiddle.net/33Cax/ and look into your `$.('#removequestions').append(html);` which should be `$('#removequestions').append(html);`, unless there is some weird noConflict stuff going on :) with `$.` hope this help, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent this way:-

```
var html = "";

html += '<input type=radio name=questions />';
$('#removequestions').append(html);​
```

### EDIT:

Another Best way of Representation:-

```
var ques = $('#removequestions');
$('<input>').attr({
    'type': 'radio',
    'name': 'questions'
}).appendTo(ques);
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/4VSde/)**